# Error Converting String to Integer

Tags: c#

Why does the below code throw a `System.FormatException` -

> Input string was not in a correct format

```
decimal sum = 0;
string valString = "3.5";

sum += Convert.ToInt32(valString);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `3.5` is not a correct **integer** value (please, notice *fraction part* - `.5`), it's `decimal` in the context:

```
decimal sum = 0;
string valString = "3.5";

sum += Convert.ToDecimal(valString);
```

Comment: So dumb I didn't think that! I did do a ToDecimal but couldn't get to understand why ToInt didnt work. Thanks a ton for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
sum += System.Convert.ToDecimal(valString);
```